# Dependency Injection in Node.js

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection

I'm reading this nice tutorial about Node.js web servers: http://nodebeginner.org/
In this part of the tutorial: http://nodebeginner.org/#whats-needed-to-route-requests they show how to do something called 'injection dependencies' in order to link both the **route** module and the **server** module to the main js file **index.js**.

I've tried exactly what they write there, but the computer won't like this. It shows me an error message:  *route is not defined*'.
I don't know what to do, please help me with this..I'm pretty new to Node.js and have never seen this kind of dependency injection before.
Thank you!

Here is the contents of index.js:

```
var server = require("./myHttp");
var router = require("./router");

server.start(router.route);
```

Here is the myHttp.js file:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start(){
function onRequest(request, response) {
  var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
  console.log("Request for "+ pathname + " recieved.");

  route(pathname);

  response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

Here is the router.js file:

```
function route(pathname) {
console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
}

exports.route = route;
```

I run the following command in the cmd: **node index.js**

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`server.start(router.route);` is called with an argument. `function start(){` is declared without arguments. The arguments is never used. Why is it there, then?

And then, a value of the argument is `router.route`. Which is just function itself. It is not called anywhere.

Comment: it is used later, but thanks for correction - I forgot to pass the 'router' as an argument for the start() function.

Comment: Since this probably solves your problem, what about a vote alternatively select?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the router file into the myHttp.js file instead:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var router = require("./router");

function start(){
function onRequest(request, response) {
  var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
  console.log("Request for "+ pathname + " recieved.");

  route(pathname);

  response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

Also now in your index.js you have to do this: ( no need for router here )

```
var server = require("./myHttp");

server.start();
```

Comment: He's talking dependency injection.

Comment: My guess is he just wants the app functioning